# Bound states of Dirac Delta function in infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

If there is a potential of $-\alpha\delta(x)$ for $-a<x<a$ and $\infty$ elsewhere, and the energy of the system is less than 0, then I'm trying to find the wave function. From the Schrodinger Equation, I've worked that wave function is

$\begin{align} 
&-\frac{\hbar}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi = E\psi \\
&k^2 = \frac{-2mE}{\hbar^2} \\
&\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\psi - k^2\psi = 0 \\
\end{align}
$

Which I solved to two parts

$A e^{kx}+ B e^{-kx}$ for $-a<x<0$

$C e^{kx} + D e^{-kx}$ for $a>x>0$.

From here, I tried the boundary conditions at $x=0,a,-a$:

$\begin{align}
&x=0: A+B=C+D \\
&x=-a: A e^{-ka} + B e^{ka} = 0 \\
&x=a: C e^{ka} + B e^{-ka} = 0 \\
\end{align}$

But I'm not sure where to go from here. I can show a relationship between the boundary conditions at x=-a and x=a, but I don't think that would give me anything valuable.

Answer (score 1):

You should also match the derivatives at $x=0$ so that they took into account the $\delta$-function. If you take smooth well $V_\epsilon(x)$ and consider small region near zero $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ where the "meat" of the well is concentrated you may then integrate the Schrodinger equation at that region,
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int\limits_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}\psi'' dx+\int\limits_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}V_\epsilon\psi dx=E\int\limits_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}\psi dx$$.
Consider now the limit of $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$. The rhs will disappear and the first integral will give the difference between the derivatives from the right and the left. So if $V_\epsilon(x)\rightarrow -\alpha\delta(x)$ you get the needed matching condition,
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\Big(\psi'|_{0+}-\psi'|_{0-}\Big)=\alpha\psi(0)$$

Comment: Which gives me $k C - k D - k A + k B = \frac{-2 m \alpha}{\hbar^2}(A+B)$ Which I still am not sure where to go with that.

Comment: Where to go? Solve the system of equations on $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$ and $k$, that's it. By the way, check the condition for $x=-a$

Comment: Is there continuity of the derivative at $x=\pm a$ also? I don't see a way to solve the system of equations with only the information I've found so far.

Comment: From the relationship of boundaries at $x=\pm a$ I can show that $C-B = (A-D)e^{-2ka}$ and using the boundary at $x=0$, I can show that $C-B = A-D$, so $1=e^{-2ka}$, right? This doesn't make sense though sense neither k nor a are 0

Comment: Ok, I don't know what happened with my last comments but you miss the option $A=D$,$C=B$.

Comment: @TheStrangeQuark For an infinite potential well, the derivative of the wave function is not continuous at the boundary (consider a finite potential and take the limit to infinity). You have 3 equations from the continuity of the wave function, one for the discontinuity of the derivative at the delta peak and one for the normalization. In total, this gives 5 equations for 4 constants and the bound state momentum. For large enough $a$ you should recover the bound state of the 1D delta well $E = -\frac{m \alpha^2}{2 \hbar^2}$